# css main content height without scrollbar

Tags: html, css

I have tried a lot.

I do not get to 100% height without scrollbars:

```css
/* =================== Global =================== */
*{
  padding: 0px;
  margin:0px;
}
html, body{
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #7a7a78;
  font-size: 11px;
  font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
}
a{
  color: #000;
  text-decoration:none;
}
header{
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin: auto;
  height: 75px;
  background-color: #d0ccc9;
}
nav{
  background-color: #964951;
  height: 30px;
}
#nav{
  max-width: 940px;
  height: 30px;
  margin: auto;
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-right: 30px;
}
section{
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 970px;
  background-color: #d0ccc9;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  height: 30px;
}
main{
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
  max-width: 970px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  background-color: #d0ccc9;
  min-height: 150px;
 height: 100%;
}
footer{
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  background-color: #964951;
  height: 75px;
  color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center; /* Vertikale Zentrierung */
  justify-content: center; /* Horizontale Zentrierung */
}
footer a{
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration:none;
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g2LjK.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cugn1.png)

can someone tell me what I did wrong?

thank you

edit: sorry, I get the css code not inserted. always the same error although everything is correct

Comment: please elaborate with your code

Comment: Show HTML and accompanying CSS.

Comment: "It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details"  -.- it's all correct...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: after feeling 100 try it has now worked

Comment: you need to post your HTML code too...

Comment: HTML would be helpful also. It's not really clear what the error is.. Are you trying to get the scroll bar? Try adding overflow: scroll; to whatever element is containing the lines of text and adjust its height accordingly.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Without seeing the HTML code it's hard to judge, but your `main` element has `height: 100%;`. So if there are other elements *outside* the `main` element (which is very likely from your CSS), they will add to the height, which will make the overall height more than 100%, which again causes the scrollbars.

Addition after added link to picture of HTML code in comments:

It's as I wrote above: Above `main` there are `header` , `nav` and `section`, below it, there is the footer. According to the CSS you posted all this adds up to 100% PLUS 210px (210px is the sum of all other heights according to your CSS): There's the overflow that causes the scrollbar.

The solution: Apply `height: calc( 100% - 210px)` to the CSS rule for `main` (instead of the 100% height there)

Comment: sorry different is not it. the editor does not let me paste the HTML code

Comment: exactly as I wrote: See the addition to my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Outside of Body (Except the head) or HTML I have nothing. With height: calc (100% - 225px); it works. Smaller to make the browser a problem:
http://www.bilder-upload.eu/upload/7936cd-1506592076.png

I do not understand why it is so

Comment: I wasn't talking about the `body`, but about the `main` element. And to allow it to become higher when there is more contant, you can use `min-height` instead of `height` (again, in `main`)

Comment: Thank you so much!
with min-height: calc (100% - 225px) it works, even if I not rausfrde why I must remove 225px

Comment: here again the HTML code as picture (Get this simply not in the post purely) http://www.bilder-upload.eu/upload/260747-1506594900.png

Comment: Hmmm...  last try (I wrote all that already in my answer, but maybe it's a language problem): Der Abschnitt `main` hat 100% Höhe (= 100% des Fensters), also bereits so viel wie das gesamte Fenster. Die Höhen der anderen Abschnitte (header, nav, section, footer) kommen noch *dazu*, wodurch die Gesamthöhe aller Elemente die Fensterhöhe übersteigt. Also zieht man für `main` 225px (das entspricht den Höhen dieser Abschnitte zusammen) von den 100% ab und kommt dadurch für den gesamten `body`(in dem sich alle diese Abschnitte + main befinden) auf genau 100% Höhe, also genau so hoch wie das Fenster.

Comment: vielen dank, ich habe es nun verstanden.   min-height: calc( 100% - 225px) = 100% browser höhe abzüglich Header, nav, section und footer = 225px. ich habe nachgerechnet und komme auf 240px aber das macht nichts da es ja nun endlich funktioniert.

Comment: vielen dank nochmal dass mir hier geholfen wurde, auch wenn der blöde foren editor meinen HTML Code nicht posten wollte